# Build a REST API with PHP on LAMP: where to put php sources?

Tags: php, rest, lamp

There are many tutorials around how to build a REST API in php, but they all seem to be either focused on using XAMPP (i.e. they explain where to put the PHP sources for XAMPP only, referring to the `htdocs`-folder) or they completely skip such explanations. So my question is: when I am working on a LAMP-stack on Ubuntu where websites and php scripts to be viewed/executed on localhost are "deployed" to `/var/www/html`, where do I have to put the code for the REST API, to be able to use it on localhost? I tried to put them into `/var/www` or `/var/www/html/` but that did not work. Any hints would be appreciated!

Comment: There’s nothing special about REST code as it relates to PHP, you can put your code anywhere. If you deploy to `/var/www/html` and put `rest.php` in that folder, it should be available at `https://example.com/rest.php`

Answer (score 0):

It is related to what folder do you choose in config. For example, default place for site folders in /etc/apache2/sites-available/mySite.local.conf

There is listen port and document root path for your site path. You can change document root for your site(s) with `DocumentRoot` key like this:

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/mySite/
```

Then you need to enable site:

```bash
sudo a2ensite mySite.local.conf
```

After it, you need to restart apache2

```bash
sudo service apache2 reload
```